# Conditional types and type narrowing

Tags: typescript, conditional-types, type-narrowing

I'm trying to solve a typing problem, here is a MWE:

```
// Typing

export type EventObject = {
    event: 'connected';
    data: boolean;
} | {
    event: 'more';
    data: string;
};

export type EventData<T, Event> = T extends { event: Event, data: unknown } ? T['data'] : never;

// Code

function dispatch<E extends EventObject['event']>(event: E, data: EventData<EventObject, E>) {
    switch(event) {
    case 'more':
        const res = data.indexOf('xxxx'); // Compiler issue: it does not know the type of data
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
}

dispatch('more', true); // The compiler works properly and tells me that data should by a string
```

As you can see, I'm using conditional types to restrict the type of `data` in the dispatcher. When I call the function, it works properly, I cannot pass a string when the event is `connected` since it should be a `boolean`.

But, when I implement the dispatcher, type narrowing does not work. The compiler is unable to determine the type of `data` when I check the type of `event`.

I'm using TS 4.8. Is there a possible workaround that could work in my case? I've searched and found nothing satisfying yet.

Comment: There are typos in the code at `EventObject['type']` and `dispatcher`.  Could you fix them and any others? Please check your example code in a standalone IDE to see that it demonstrates your issue (and only your issue)

Comment: Creating a union of possible arguments represented as tuples, then destructuring and using `if` statements to check for the event type works: https://tsplay.dev/wjQMvW, but interestingly enough, using `switch` breaks again. Also tried using `if` in your original code but it did not work.

Comment: Generic conditional types are opaque to the compiler and it cannot use control flow analysis to narrow them (see [ms/TS#33912](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33912)).  In general the only work around is to loosen things with type assertions, but for this particular example code I'd think you could just forget about generics and conditional types and use a discriminated union of input param lists like [this playground link](//tsplay.dev/WJ5Pgm) shows.  Does that address your question? If so I can write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: From what I've seen, both of your suggestions work for me. I understand the typing of @kelly, but I'm not sure I'm comfortable with yours, jcalz, would elaborate of how it works, plz? Thanks a mil!

Comment: It's essentially doing the same as mine, except utilizing [distributive conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types), while mine uses a mapped type to get each key.

Comment: Yeah, both are methods to distribute a type function over a union.  Anyway, I will assume @kelly will write an answer here, but if someone does want me to write one, please mention me with the @ signal so I'll be notified.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One solution is to create a union of all the possible argument pairs represented as tuples. Here I have chosen to use a mapped type:

```
type PossibleArgs = {
    [K in EventObject["event"]]: [
        event: K,
        data: Extract<EventObject, { event: K }>["data"]
    ];
}[EventObject["event"]];

function dispatch(...args: PossibleArgs) {
    const [event, data] = args;

    if (event === "more") data.indexOf("XXX"); // OK
    else if (event === "connected") data; // boolean
    else data; // never
}
```

You can also utilize [distributive conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types) as @jcalz demonstrated:

```
type PossibleArgs = EventObject extends infer E ? E extends EventObject ?
    [event: E["event"], data: E["data"]] : never : never;
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/mM1eVm)